# Guess the colour of the blocks ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

in this program i am creating, there are four different coloured blocks(red, green, blue, and yellow. The computer hides three different coloured blocks from the user. The user then tries to guess the colours and the order of the blocks. After guessing the colour of the three hidden blocks, the computer displays how many of the colours are correct and how many of the colours are in the right position. the trouble that i am having is this the functions checkColoursCorrect() and checkPositionsCorrect(). i am always getting either 0 for both in the outcome or 1. i never get 2 or 3 positions/colours right.please tell me what i did wrong.
This is my code:

```
btnCheckGuess.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkGuess);

btnNewGame.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, newGame);

// Declare Global Variables

var computerBlock1:String;  // the computer's first block

var computerBlock2:String;  // the computer's second block

var computerBlock3:String;  // the computer's third block


function checkGuess(e:MouseEvent):void
{  
var userGuess1:String;   
var userGuess2:String  
var userGuess3:String;    
var coloursCorrect:int;     
var positionsCorrect:int;   


userGuess1 = txtinBlock1.text;
userGuess2 = txtinBlock2.text;
userGuess3 = txtinBlock3.text;
userGuess1 = userGuess1.toUpperCase();
userGuess2 = userGuess2.toUpperCase();
userGuess3 = userGuess3.toUpperCase();

coloursCorrect = checkColoursCorrect(userGuess1,userGuess2,userGuess3);
positionsCorrect = checkPositionsCorrect(userGuess1,userGuess2,userGuess3);
lblOutput.text = "Number of Colours Correct = " + coloursCorrect.toString() + "\r";
lblOutput.text += "Number of Positions Correct = " + positionsCorrect.toString();
}


// g1– the user's guess of the first block
// g2– the user's guess of the second block
// g3– the user's guess of the third block

function checkColoursCorrect(g1:String,g2:String,g3:String):int
{

if(g1 == computerBlock1){
    return 1
}

if(g2 == computerBlock2){
    return 1
}

if(g3 == computerBlock3){
    return 1
}
return 0;
}


// g1– the user's guess of the first block
// g2– the user's guess of the second block
// g3- the user's guess of the third block
function checkPositionsCorrect(g1:String,g2:String,g3:String):int
{

if(g1 == computerBlock1){
    return 1
}
if(g2 == computerBlock2){
    return 1
}
if(g3 == computerBlock3){
    return 1
}
return 0;   
}

function newGame(e:MouseEvent):void
{
var block1:int;     
var block2:int;     // numbers representing hidden block
var block3:int;     

// generate three unique numbers between 1 and 4 for the block numbers
block1 = randomWholeNumber(4,1);
block2 = randomWholeNumber(4,1);
block3 = randomWholeNumber(4,1);

// convert block numbers to letters 1-R, 2-G, 3-B, 4-Y
if (block1 == 1) {
    computerBlock1 = "R";
} else if (block1 == 2) {
    computerBlock1 = "G";
} else if (block1 == 3) {
    computerBlock1 = "B";
} else if (block1 == 4) {
    computerBlock1 = "Y";
}

if (block2 == 1) {
    computerBlock2 = "R";
} else if (block2 == 2) {
    computerBlock2 = "G";
} else if (block2 == 3) {
    computerBlock2 = "B";
} else if (block2 == 4) {
    computerBlock2 = "Y";
}

if (block3 == 1) {
    computerBlock3 = "R";
} else if (block3 == 2) {
    computerBlock3 = "G";
} else if (block3 == 3) {
    computerBlock3 = "B";
} else if (block3 == 4) {
    computerBlock3 = "Y";
}

txtinBlock1.text = "";
txtinBlock2.text = "";
txtinBlock3.text = "";
lblOutput.text = "";
}

function randomWholeNumber(highNumber:int,lowNumber:int):int

{

return Math.floor((highNumber - lowNumber + 1) * Math.random() + lowNumber);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding of what `return` does. Both of your methods will only ever return 0 or 1.

I believe that what you actually want to do is increment a value every time the user has guessed something correctly, and then return that value:

```
function checkColoursCorrect(g1:String,g2:String,g3:String):int
{
    var coloursCorrect:int = 0; 
    if(g1 == computerBlock1){
        coloursCorrect++;
    }

    if(g2 == computerBlock2){
        coloursCorrect++;
    }

    if(g3 == computerBlock3){
        coloursCorrect++;
    }
    return coloursCorrect;
}
```